# How do I load a replaceable file inside a react component library?

Tags: reactjs, components, load, assets

I am developing a react component library that needs to load additional content from a file which has to stay replaceable.

The challenging thing is to keep the react apps package.json and webpack config files as is, without hardcoding library related stuff inside.

Additionally I have set up a demo project on GitHub for your convenience.

https://github.com/fix-me/react-library-load-asset

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Webpack seems to be obsolete in such things. If you stumbled upon this finding, having similar troubles, consider using the follow up tool rollup. With this I was able to do exactly what I needed to. Here is a great article that describes it in detail: https://medium.com/@kelin2025/so-you-wanna-use-es6-modules-714f48b3a953. Nevertheless webpack is a very great tool for application bundling!